# Why cant i access xml files under drawable?

Tags: java, android

First of all i am extremely new to android and i dont know much about it.I am trying to play around with it and i am right now following this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

I have created a class as below

```
package com.example.tabbedactivity;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class TabbedActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");
        songspec.setIndicator("Songs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
        videospec.setIndicator("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos ta
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_tabbed, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and accordingly i have made three xml files under drawable like shown below
icon_photos_tab.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo-hover"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo-unhover" />
</selector>
```

icon_songs_tab.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/music-hover"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/music-unhover" />
</selector>
```

icon_videos_tab.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/video-hover"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/video-unhover" />
</selector>
```

now the IDE shows problem when i try to access these xml files under drawable precisely the line of codes shown below which are  part of TabbedActivity.java (the class that i have shown above)

```
TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");
            songspec.setIndicator("Songs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));


TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
            // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
            photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));


TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
            videospec.setIndicator("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
```

and the error says

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - icon_photos_tab cannot be resolved or is       not a field
>     - R.drawable cannot be resolved to a variable

What exactly could be the problem.(I am really really new to android .This is kind of liek my first app and i havenot gone through any theory )

update 
I get following erros on the console

```
[2013-01-12 12:32:02 - TabbedActivity] res\drawable-ldpi\video-hover.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2013-01-12 12:32:02 - TabbedActivity] res\drawable-mdpi\video-hover.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2013-01-12 12:32:02 - TabbedActivity] res\drawable-xhdpi\video-hover.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2013-01-12 12:32:02 - TabbedActivity] res\drawable-hdpi\video-unhover.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2013-01-12 12:32:02 - TabbedActivity] res\drawable-ldpi\video-unhover.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2013-01-12 12:32:02 - TabbedActivity] res\drawable-mdpi\video-unhover.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2013-01-12 12:32:02 - TabbedActivity] res\drawable-xhdpi\video-unhover.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android resource file name should not contain `'-'` or capital letter. The above error shows that file name contains `'-'` char. So change the `'-'` as under score `'_'`. Change your drawable image files like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the name of files are creating the problems.Change the name of photo-hover and photo-unhover to photo_hover and photo_unhover and see if it works...

Comment: Thank you so much.That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**LISTEN TO YOUR ERRORS!**

I don't mean to sound rude, but the problem is up on a soapbox outside your open window with a loudspeaker:

> res\drawable-xhdpi\video-unhover.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

**must contain only [a-z0-9_.]**, This tells you that only lower case characters `a` through `z`, numbers `0` through `9`, the `_` and `.` characters are allowed in XML filenames.  Your filename has a hyphen `-` in it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to reference a resource (icon_photos_tab) that doesn't exist.  You would need a resource (either an XML drawable or a PNG or something) in your drawable folder with that name.

Good luck.

Comment: hey there but icon_photos_tab.xml does exist under drawable so do other two xml files that are required.

Comment: do photo-hover and photo-unhover exist?

Comment: yes they do.I see no error in the xml files(icon_photos_tab.xml) at all.

Answer (score 0):

the reason behind this error is that there is an error in some of your xml file.

Check your res/ folder in order to be sure that every file it contains have no error. 
it causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have put your XML files under the /res/drawable folder? Cleaning and re-building the project might also help.